# "Requests for a collection must have a trailing slash on the URI" error

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, mod-dav-svn

I have a svn server (VisualSVN Server 3.2), it works fine, but in a Windows Event Viewer I found many

> Requests for a collection must have a trailing slash on the URI. [301, #175002] 
>   [client 127.0.0.1]
>
> Could not fetch resource information.  [301, #0] 
>   [client 127.0.0.1]

what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The question should be asked at ServerFault, not StackOverflow.*

The error-level event is logged when a user navigates to URL `https://svn.example.com/svn/myrepo` (without trialing slash).

This is not really a problem, however the fact that VisualSVN Server writes an error-level event might be confusing. I guess that this can be improved in future VisualSVN Server updates, thank you for the report!.